# Kendo chart with different granularity/base unit data

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-chart

I have to show data on kendo chart, using line and area type of chart. Data is fetched from REST service and comes as json of dictionaries of date-value pairs.

Each serie can contain different granularity/base unit. So, for example, I have two series, one of which has **year** and the other **month** base unit and both have to be represented on one chart.

Now the problem: my client wants to connect each value in the series with lines (or areas in case of area type chart) but only if dates are sequential. So a pair '1 jan 2015' and '1 feb 2015' should be connected but '1 jan 2015' and '1 mar 2015' shouldn't.

Kendo has an option missingValues: 'gap', that works for this scenario, but only for the same granularity series. In this dojo http://dojo.telerik.com/aWiCO I have two series and one category axis, but year type points are not connected, which is justified in this case, but not desired. On the other hand, 'interpolate' option will connect every point in the series, so in case of missing value in particular serie this behavior is incorrect.

So to connect the points I had an idea of creating more X axes (and hiding all but one) and adding each series for different axis. For an example, I created one X axis for month gran data and then second X axis for year gran data. Now axes are divided properly, but values on chart are put sequentially, not in date order. You can see this behavior here: http://dojo.telerik.com/AcIBa

I'm pretty much stuck there, as I have no more ideas how to fix this problem. Pointing me in the right direction would be highly appreciated.